# How to give Rounded rectangular shape for FadeInImage.assetNetwork image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am using FadeInImage.assetNetwork to display my image. But no matter what I try I am not getting the rounded rectangular border.I tried Clipperrect but the image doesnt get clipped but the card gets cliped.I even tried wrapping the FadeInImage.assetNetwork in CLipperect and tried to wrap in container and give decoration  like this.But nothing seems to give desired results.

In short the image is not clipped but the card is getting clipped.How do we solve this?

```
decoration: ShapeDecoration(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10),
      ),
Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.27,
              color: Colors.black,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: __moviesMovieId.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(

                  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 15, 0),
                  child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                    image:
                        'https://img.youtube.com/vi/${__moviesMovieId[index].substring(8)}/0.jpg',
                    placeholder: cupertinoActivityIndicator,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PhysicalModel(
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
    color: Colors.black,
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
    child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
      image:
          'https://img.youtube.com/vi/${__moviesMovieId[index].substring(8)}/0.jpg',
      placeholder: "hey",
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
  ),
```

Replace yout Card from ListView Builder to this , works absolutely fine . the above other answer wasnt working in my device so i answered . Do mark it as answer if it helps

Comment: I have to say ,this helps but the problem it at the corners of the rectangle I want a smooth  rounded corner and this is giving pretty harsh curvatures                                                                                I tried this thing  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
                    ),
but I am not getting the smooth ones like how it is in this pic https://flutter-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Rounded_Corner_Rectangle_thumb.png

Comment: I have updated my clipbehaviour , with that you could use your border radius  , just use the exact code . Mark this as answer , if it helps

Comment: Yes,it works like a charm,thanks.I will mark as correct.Also could you please let me know from where u actually learnt.It will be helpful for other also.Thank u so much once again

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(

                  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 15, 0),
                  child: Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
               
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(25.0),
topRight:Radius.circular(25.0),
bottomLeft:Radius.circular(25.0),
),
child:FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                    image:
                        'https://img.youtube.com/vi/${__moviesMovieId[index].substring(8)}/0.jpg',
                    placeholder: cupertinoActivityIndicator,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
),
),
```

Alternately,

You can also do all these,

```
decoration: ShapeDecoration(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10),
      ),
```

Just before `FadeInImage.assetNetwork` (wrap  `FadeInImage.assetNetwork` inside that) to achieve what you want

Comment: Please upvote and and accept this as the answer if it helped

Comment: ,it didnt help .The images are still like that only